# Calculation Script for SSAS project

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to write a script in my SSAS project (cube calculation) that calculate Opening and closing stock value on specific date.

[image]

In this screen short first table showing my raw data and second table is showing my required BI values .

Opening stk (stock) on `2015-02-01` product A was 18 and that day price was 10 so `10*18 = 180` stk value,

on 2015-02-08 price was 9 for same product and closing stk was 10 (so 9*10=90) is a closing stock value.

I have use below code for this but this script is not showing required results.

```
 Scope([Measures].[Closing Stock]);                                                                
        This = sum((
        null:[Time].[Year].CurrentMember  *
        null:[Time].[Quarter].CurrentMember *
        null:[Time].[Month Name].CurrentMember *
        null:[Time].[Month].CurrentMember *
        null:[Time].[date].CurrentMember )
       ,[Measures].[Movement Qty]) * Price;                                                                
       FORMAT_STRING ( This ) = "#,#";                                                                
       End Scope;
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "not showing required results". Is it close to the solution? totally wrong? what are you expecting from us?

Comment: **In simple i want to convert my below SQL Query in to SSAS .**

select sum(p.movement) Stock
  ,
  ((select top 1  price from ItemMovement_New ch 
        where ch.ITEMID='10003226' and  ch.Store='F-GJK' and ch.SaleDate <='2019-06-01' 
        order by SaleDate desc)) Price, 
  sum(p.movement) +  ((select top 1  price from ItemMovement_New ch 
            where ch.ITEMID='10003226' and  ch.Store='F-GJK' and ch.SaleDate <='2019-06-01' 
            order by SaleDate desc)) [Stock Value]
from ItemMovement_New p
where Store='F-GJK'  and ITEMID='10003226' and SaleDate <='2019-06-01'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I understand you want to display the remaining stock and the remaining stock value for each day. The script below will work only at day levels. I am have assumed that you have the following measurse in your cube [Meausres].[Opening],[Measures].[Qty],[Measures].[Price] and you have [date] dimension and a level named [date] in this dimension

```
with 
member measure.ClosingCount 
as
sum([date].[date].currentmember, [Meausres].[Opening]-[Measures].[Qty])

member measure.ClosingAmount 
as
sum([date].[date].currentmember, [measure].[ClosingCount]*[Measures].[Price] )
```

Edit based on the comment

```
with 
    member measure.ClosingCount 
    as
    sum(([date].[date].currentmember,[Product].[Product].currentmember), [Meausres].[Opening]-[Measures].[Qty])

    member measure.ClosingAmount 
    as
    sum(([date].[date].currentmember,[Product].[Product].currentmember), [measure].[ClosingCount]*[Measures].[Price] )
```

Comment: Dear MoazRub, You are right i need remaining stock value for each day. but shared script by you is not giving us a correct result, this script showing total stock * total price for example we have five rows in two row stock was 10 and price was $10 in second row stock was 8 and price was $5 so above script calculation 8 * 15 although we need 8* last price of x item

Comment: @AbidAli kindly share the results of my script and the query you ran. Plus also share what should be returned by sharing the same result worked in excel

Comment: can you guide me i want to share some screen short but con't in comments window, can you share with me your email or other contact?

Comment: @AbidAli check the edit it should help. You can contact me at moazrubku@yahoo.com

Comment: **Need to Convert SQL Query in SSAS Script:-**  <br/>

select sum(p.movement) Stock
  ,
  ((select top 1  price from ItemMovement_New ch 
        where ch.ITEMID='10003226' and  ch.Store='F-GJK' and ch.SaleDate <='2019-06-01' 
        order by SaleDate desc)) Price, 
  sum(p.movement) +  ((select top 1  price from ItemMovement_New ch 
            where ch.ITEMID='10003226' and  ch.Store='F-GJK' and ch.SaleDate <='2019-06-01' 
            order by SaleDate desc)) [Stock Value]
from ItemMovement_New p
where Store='F-GJK'  and ITEMID='10003226' and SaleDate <='2019-06-01'